# Blank space in the y direction between card element when maping through array, what is the reason?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm creating a React project with Tailwindcss, I have an array of objects (projects). I'm mapping through them and returning Card components. When the flex wrap takes action there are blank spaces between the cards in the y direction which I can't seem to figure out why.
Main:

```
<div className="w-full h-full flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-start items-start gap-x-10">
          {filteredProjects.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div className="w-fit h-fit" key={item.pid}>
                <ProjectCard project={item} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

And the Card component:

```
<div
      onClick={openProjectModal}
      className="bg-secondaryBG rounded-xl min-w-[240px] min-h-[140px] p-2 hover:cursor-pointer"
    >
      <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col">
        <div className="w-full h-fit flex flex-row flex-nowrap justify-between items-center px-1 gap-4">
          <div className="text-xl font-semibold">{project.name}</div>
          <div className="h-full hover:cursor-help">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              strokeWidth="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
              className="w-6 h-6 text-stone-500 mt-1"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                d="M10.343 3.94c.09-.542.56-.94 1.11-.94h1.093c.55 0 1.02.398 1.11.94l.149.894c.07.424.384.764.78.93.398.164.855.142 1.205-.108l.737-.527a1.125 1.125 0 011.45.12l.773.774c.39.389.44 1.002.12 1.45l-.527.737c-.25.35-.272.806-.107 1.204.165.397.505.71.93.78l.893.15c.543.09.94.56.94 1.109v1.094c0 .55-.397 1.02-.94 1.11l-.893.149c-.425.07-.765.383-.93.78-.165.398-.143.854.107 1.204l.527.738c.32.447.269 1.06-.12 1.45l-.774.773a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.449.12l-.738-.527c-.35-.25-.806-.272-1.203-.107-.397.165-.71.505-.781.929l-.149.894c-.09.542-.56.94-1.11.94h-1.094c-.55 0-1.019-.398-1.11-.94l-.148-.894c-.071-.424-.384-.764-.781-.93-.398-.164-.854-.142-1.204.108l-.738.527c-.447.32-1.06.269-1.45-.12l-.773-.774a1.125 1.125 0 01-.12-1.45l.527-.737c.25-.35.273-.806.108-1.204-.165-.397-.505-.71-.93-.78l-.894-.15c-.542-.09-.94-.56-.94-1.109v-1.094c0-.55.398-1.02.94-1.11l.894-.149c.424-.07.765-.383.93-.78.165-.398.143-.854-.107-1.204l-.527-.738a1.125 1.125 0 01.12-1.45l.773-.773a1.125 1.125 0 011.45-.12l.737.527c.35.25.807.272 1.204.107.397-.165.71-.505.78-.929l.15-.894z"
              />
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full h-fit mt-4 mb-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <DateShower started={project.started} finished={project.finished} />
        </div>
        <div className="w-full h-fit flex flex-row flex-nowrap justify-between mb-2 px-3">
          <div className="w-fit h-full flex flex-row flex-nowrap gap-2 justify-center items-center text-lg">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              strokeWidth="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
              className="w-6 h-6"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                d="M9 12h3.75M9 15h3.75M9 18h3.75m3 .75H18a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V6.108c0-1.135-.845-2.098-1.976-2.192a48.424 48.424 0 00-1.123-.08m-5.801 0c-.065.21-.1.433-.1.664 0 .414.336.75.75.75h4.5a.75.75 0 00.75-.75 2.25 2.25 0 00-.1-.664m-5.8 0A2.251 2.251 0 0113.5 2.25H15c1.012 0 1.867.668 2.15 1.586m-5.8 0c-.376.023-.75.05-1.124.08C9.095 4.01 8.25 4.973 8.25 6.108V8.25m0 0H4.875c-.621 0-1.125.504-1.125 1.125v11.25c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125h9.75c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.375c0-.621-.504-1.125-1.125-1.125H8.25zM6.75 12h.008v.008H6.75V12zm0 3h.008v.008H6.75V15zm0 3h.008v.008H6.75V18z"
              />
            </svg>
            {project.taskCount}
          </div>
          <div className="w-fit h-full flex flex-row flex-nowrap gap-2 justify-center items-center text-lg">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              strokeWidth="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
              className="w-6 h-6"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                d="M15 19.128a9.38 9.38 0 002.625.372 9.337 9.337 0 004.121-.952 4.125 4.125 0 00-7.533-2.493M15 19.128v-.003c0-1.113-.285-2.16-.786-3.07M15 19.128v.106A12.318 12.318 0 018.624 21c-2.331 0-4.512-.645-6.374-1.766l-.001-.109a6.375 6.375 0 0111.964-3.07M12 6.375a3.375 3.375 0 11-6.75 0 3.375 3.375 0 016.75 0zm8.25 2.25a2.625 2.625 0 11-5.25 0 2.625 2.625 0 015.25 0z"
              />
            </svg>
            {project.userCount}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Picture of black space:
[blank_space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuwmH.png)

I already tried setting the Card's div margins to 0 and also tried "gap-y-0" none of those worked. I'm curious why this is happening and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is most likely the `h-full` class in the cards container.

It's taking the full height of its parent container (not shown in your code), and the cards inside it are being distributed accordingly, i.e., each row gets half of the height.

To fix this just remove the `h-full` class. Also `flex-row` is the default, so you can remove that too.

```js
<div className="w-full flex flex-wrap justify-start items-start gap-x-10">
  {filteredProjects.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className="w-fit h-fit" key={item.pid}>
        <ProjectCard project={item} />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

---

For future posts (or for this one in case my answer isn't exactly right), I'd suggest you post the full code (within reason) and add a reproducible example using something like https://play.tailwindcss.com/, as that helps people who are answering your question, so you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks! You were right. Also thanks for your suggestion about my future posts!